# Representing a creation of list and dictionary using comprehensions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some questions related to the program I wrote. The data I have is following

```
data = ['Sectors', 'Countries', 'Regions', 6, 9, 4, 2, 3, 0]
columns = {'countries': 'Countries', 'regions': 'Regions', 'sectors': 'Sectors'}
column_size = 3
```

To convert into a specific dictionary based on the number of columns provided, I use the strategy to write 2 functions. The first function is converting into a 2-dimensional list where 1st item of the 2d list provides the column names while other items representing values. The second function gives the expected output by mapping the key and values based on the position where it is situated

```
Output: {'Sectors': [6, 2], 'Countries': [9, 3], 'Regions': [4, 0]}
```

The following is my code

```
def converting_to_two_dimensional_list(data: list, column_size: int):
    list_two_dimensional = []
    for l in range(0, len(data), column_size):
        buffer = []
        for j in range(l, l+column_size):
            buffer.append(data[j])
        list_two_dimensional.append(buffer)
    return list_two_dimensional

def final_result(list_two_dimensional: list):
    final_output = {}
    for c in list_two_dimensional[0]:
        buffer = []
        for d in range(len(list_two_dimensional[1:])):
            buffer.append(list_two_dimensional[1:][d][list_two_dimensional[0].index(c)])
        final_output.update({c:buffer})
    return final_output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = final_result(converting_to_two_dimensional_list(data, column_size))
    print(result)
```

Although I got the expected output, is there any way to represent those functions using comprehension, and if no then , is there any optimized way to get the same output?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use list comprehension

```py
data = ['Sectors', 'Countries', 'Regions', 6, 9, 4, 2, 3, 0]
column_size = 3
d = data[column_size:]

output = dict(zip(data[0:column_size], [[d[j] for j in range(i, len(d), column_size)] for i in range(column_size)]))

print(output) #{'Sectors': [6, 2], 'Countries': [9, 3], 'Regions': [4, 0]}
```

Comment: updated `i in range(column_size)` from `i in range(len(d))` since later generates unnecessary list which is not required.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options you can use to make this much more pythonic, yes. While it's easy to make a pythonic version that gets your desired output, I'm not sure about which general problem you're trying to solve and so will provide a few example functions below for different options.

The first option I can think of is that you have a fixed number of elements for each key, which you could achieve with the following:

```
def format_data(data, num_keys, num_values = 2):
    # Use slicing to get the two halves of the list
    keys, values = data[:num_keys], data[num_keys:]

    # Use enumerate and num_values to iterate over the keys and get the values
    return {key: values[num_values * i : num_values * (i + 1)] for i, key in enumerate(keys)}
```

The second option I can think of is similar to the first, but you instead want to evenly distribute the values among the keys, thus if you had 2 keys and 8 values, each would get 4 values:

```
def format_data(data, num_keys):
    # Use slicing to get the two halves of the list
    keys, values = data[:num_keys], data[num_keys:]

    # Use integer division get the number of values for each key
    num_values = values // num_keys

    # Use enumerate and num_values to iterate over the keys and get the values
    return {key: values[num_values * i : num_values * (i + 1)] for i, key in enumerate(keys)}
```